# ProxySQL insert mirroring

Tags: mysql

I started to play around ProxySQL, with it as front-end server and three standalone mysql 5.7 as back-end server.
Surfing web, I found a lot of useful examples, but I didn't find a way to mirror on all back-end servers the modification statements (Insert, Update, Delete).
Is it possible?

Any useful suggestion?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Might get more traction on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> INSERT INTO
>   mysql_query_rules(rule_id,active,match_digest,mirror_hostgroup,apply)
>   VALUES (12,1,"^(INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE|SELECT.*FOR UPDATE$)",7,1);